# Sharepoint 2010 Accordion Quicklaunch Help

Tags: quick-launch

I'm in direct need of assistance with getting my sites Quick Launch Current Navigation collapsible/accordion. I've tried almost all the preferred code on the web with no success.

I'm unable to find a proper code that would enable this feature.

**Code**:

```
<script src="/sites/g1/Scripts/jquery%20Codes/jquery-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.menu-vertical>ul.root>li.static>a").toggle(function() {
            $(">ul", $(this).parent()).show("fast");
        }, function() {
            $(">ul", $(this).parent()).hide("fast");
        });
        $("div.menu-vertical>ul.root>li.static>ul.static").css("display", "none");
        var s = $("div.menu-vertical>ul.root>li.static>ul.static>li.selected").parent();
        var p = s.parent();
        p.find('ul').css("display", "");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: @Asad Refai, thanks for replying to my request for help. I am using the below code.

Comment: Not required, you can get your query done here on SE.

Comment: Not sure if applicable to this case but check out Jquery UI. It has an accordion feature that is very nice.

Comment: @Roland, the accordion I'm using is for my Quicklaunch. It collapses but doesn't expand when clicked. I'm not able to get the toggle function working.

Comment: @AsadRefai based on the code attached do you see anything that I'm doing wrong? I'm using SharePoint server. I'm able to get the Quick launch Headers to collapse but the sub items will not expand when clicked. I'm not able to get the toggle function working. any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code I guess it might work.

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".s4-ql ul.root ul").hide();

                $(".s4-ql ul.root > li ").mouseover(
                function()
                                {
                                $(".s4-ql ul.root ul").hide();
                                $(this).children(".s4-ql ul.root > li > ul").slideDown("slow");

                }
                );

});